# How can I use ref in WCF?

Tags: wcf, pass-by-reference, ref

Can't I use ref in WCF to return data ?

This is my WCF file.

> public myDataset SearchInfo(string accountName, string accountId, **ref**
>   int totalRecords)

Although totalRecords is a **non-zero number**, I always get **0**.
I have to get both myDataset and totalRecords.
How should I try?
I am new to WCF.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE :**

It works well. My bad !!!

Comment: Can you show the code that gives a value to totalRecords, you should be able to use ref parameters

Comment: Yes, shold work. Show the code how you set the value of totalRecords

Comment: in fact, I intentionally assign totalRecords = 10 and try to call this Service from another project. I get the return myDataset but I only get zero for totalRecords. Do I need some configuration in WCF ?


         __DS= serviceClient.SearchInfo(accountName, accountId, ref totalRecords);__



This is my call to WCF.

Comment: It works well with ref !!! My bad !!! Thx guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to return multiple values, it's probably better to add a data contract with a data member for each value (dataset and total records in your case).

```
[DataContract]
public class SearchInfoResult
{
  [DataMember]
  public myDataSet DataSet {get; set;}

  [DataMember]
  public int TotalRecords {get; set;}
}
```